Running average works with DF-I but not with DF-II
I'm curious what are the assumptions (about coefficients and input signal) under which DF-I and DF-II are numerically equivalent -- or, what are the boundary conditions where they differ.
(I'm not extremely well versed in filter theory, btw, picked up bits and pieces but not systematic.)
The situation is that I was trying to use SuperCollider's FOS (First Order Section) to calculate a running average: over n >= 0, y(n) = (x(n) / (n+1)) + (y(n-1) * n/(n+1)), so, if a0 and a1 are feedforward coefficients and b1 is the feedback coefficient (all positive: the feedback coefficient is inverted from JOS), a0 = 1/(n+1), a1 = 0 and b1 = 1 - a0. This works perfectly with DF-I.
Note: I'm aware of threads here about moving average, but I was working on running average.
In DF-II, manually unpacking the calculation (and providing a constant DC = 1 at the input, as a test, because the running average of 1 should be 1):
n = 0, then a0 = 1 and b1 = 0:

v(0) = x(0) = 1  (b1 = 0 in this cycle, so this term disappears)
y(0) = a0v(0) = x(0)  (a1 = 0 so that term disappears)

= 1



n = 1, then a0 = 0.5, b1 = 0.5:

v(1) = x(1) + 0.5x(0)
y(1) = 0.5x(1) + 0.5 · 0.5x(0) + 0v(0)

= 0.5x(1) + 0.25x(0) and we have already deviated from "running average"
= 3/4



n = 2, then a0 = 1/3, b1 = 2/3:

v(2) = x(2) + 2/3(x(1) + 1/2x(0)) = x(2) + 2/3x(1) + 1/3x(0)
y(2) = 1/3(x(2) + 2/3x(1) + 1/3x(0)) + 0v(1)

= 1/3x(2) + 2/9x(1) + 1/9x(0)
= 2/3



Over time, this converges asymptotically toward 0.5, where DF-I produces a constant 1.0.
I looked at Julius Smith for the DF details -- which aren't derived, just asserted -- the text seems to imply that DF-I and DF-II are the same, but clearly they are not. (I went down this rabbit hole because SC's FOS documentation claims that the formula is "equivalent to" (a0 * x(n)) + (a1 * x(n-1)) + (b1 * y(n-1)).) So I assume there are some conditions on the use of DF-II, outside of which DF-II is invalid. My best guess is that DF-II assumes time-invariance, or at least a slow rate of change in the coefficients... is this guess correct?
Thanks,
hjh


My best guess is that DF-II assumes time-invariance... is this guess correct?

Yes.
The filter you are implemented is time variant and hence is NOT an LTI (linear time invariant) system. The different filter topologies are only equivalent for LTI systems, so there is no reason to expect DF-I and DF-II giving the same results.
Specifically DF-II uses the $b_1$ and $a_1$ coefficients from the previous time step. That's fine for an LTI system since the coefficients are constant and don't change with time.
For a time variant system DF-I is the way to go and you get
$$y[n] = b_0[n]x[n] + b_1[n-1]x[n-1] - a_1[n]y[n-1] $$
